# What is DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl

Does anybody know what is DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx?
What its use? and the most important, **when** it is in use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A test page is auto-generated for web-services in ASP.NET.

DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx is used to generate that test page.

You can modify this generator to change how the test page is generated.

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2004/03/10/87327.aspx)